# Lettuce fail over in cluster

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am trying to get Lettuce to connect to the newly promoted master (former slave) after the old one failed. But all writes stop. The writes continue after the failed host reconnects, now as a slave. And it continues to write to the new master (former slave).

I tried setting periodic topology refreshes, as well as adaptive ones on all events but it didn't help. Is there another setting I have to use?

This is how I configured the client:

```
final List<RedisURI> redisURIs = buildRedisURIs(redisServerSettings.getNodes());
final RedisClusterClient client = RedisClusterClient.create(clientResources, redisURIs);
final ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions refreshOptions =
        ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                                     .enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers()
                                     .adaptiveRefreshTriggersTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                                     .refreshTriggersReconnectAttempts(2)
                                     .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                                     .build();
client.setOptions(ClusterClientOptions.builder().topologyRefreshOptions(refreshOptions).build());
```

Comment: Which version of lettuce are you running? I literally just had this happen to me this morning. There's https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/releases for 5.2.0 that references https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/672 which seems like it theoretically might help. but don't know.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like it only adds a new refresh trigger -- in my case, the whole client got recreated part way through -- i.e. after the aws event log (and a dump of node state from lettuce) claimed that the slave had been promoted -- and so I see 4 masters (on 3 shards) with old master having flags `flags=[MASTER, FAIL]`  Once the old master reconnected, everything went ok.

Comment: Github bug now here->https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/1152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Because lettuce doesn't have a timeout normally, it waited forever for the response from the server. Setting the timeout caused some transactions to fail but after the failed transactions, the reads and writes continued.

Comment: In my case, I had to setup both timeout + topology refresh.